# NodeJS function getting interrupted by socketio event

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I'm seeing some strange behavior in my nodejs game server in which there appears to be concurrency. This is strange because Nodejs is supposed to run in one thread as it doesn't use any concurrency. The problem is that I have an update function that's repeatedly called using setImmediate(). In this function I am using an array in two places. However, this same array is also modified when the "disconnect" event fires (which is when the client disconnects from the server). So it so happens that when the timing aligns so that the disconnect event fires AFTER the first place in which the array is accessed in the update function but BEFORE the second place, the array is modified and so the server crashes when the array is attempted to be accessed in the second place.

Here's some code that might make this picture clear:

```
function update(){
    for(var i = 0; i < gameWorlds.length; i++){
        gameWorlds[i].update();
        console.log("GAMEWORLDS LENGTH BEFORE: " + gameWorlds.length);
        NetworkManager.sendToClient(gameWorlds[i].id, "gameupdate", gameWorlds[i].getState());
        console.log("GAMEWORLDS LENGTH AFTER: " + gameWorlds.length);
        gameWorlds[i].clearGameState();
    }
}

setImmediate(update);

//in the NetworkManager module, the disconnect event handler:
socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    for(var a = 0; a < sockets.length; a++){
       if(sockets[a].id === socket.id){
                sockets.splice(a, 1);
             }
        }
        listenerFunction("disconnect", socket.id);
        console.log("Client " + socket.id + " DISCONNECTED!");
});

//also in the NetworkManager module, the sendToClient function:
function sendToClient(clientId, messageName, data){
    for(var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++){
        if(sockets[i].id === clientId){
            sockets[i].emit(messageName, data);
        }
    }
}

//in the main module (the same one as the update function), the listener      
//function that's called in the disconnect event handler:
function networkEventsListener(eventType, eventObject){
   if(eventType === "disconnect"){
       for(var i = 0; i < gameWorlds.length; i++){
            if(gameWorlds[i].id === eventObject){
                gameWorlds.splice(i, 1); 
                console.log("GAME WORLD DELETED");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Now, I have a socketio event listener set up for when the client disconnects in which an element in the array is deleted. When this event occurs RIGHT in between the first and second places the array is accessed (as shown above), my server crashes. Either threads are being used or my function is stopped to let the event handler execute and then my function is resumed. Either way, I don't want this to be happening. Thank you!

EDIT 1: I edited the code to incorporate the console logs I have in my code. The reason why I am saying my loop is getting interrupted is because of the fact that the second console log outputs a length of 0 while the first console log outputs it greater than 0. Also, there is another console log in the disconnect event handler which FIRES in between the two console logs in my update function. This means that my function is getting interrupted.

EDIT 2: Thank you for all your replies I really appreciate it. I think there's been some confusion regarding:
1. The fact that no one has acknowledged how the console logs are appearing. In my previous edit, I changed the code to reflect how I am logging to see the problem. The issue is that in the disconnect event handler, I have a console log which is happening in between the two console logs in the loop. I.e. the disconnect event handler executes BEFORE the second console log is reached in the loop. Unless I am confused about the implementation of the console log function, the logs should be happening in the correct order (that is that the two console logs in the loop should always occur before any other console log in the rest of the program due to the ASYNC nature as most of you have stated.) But this is not the case, which leads me to believe something strange is happening.
2. None of the code inside the loop is changing the array. In a lot of your replies, you assume that there is code which actually modifies the array INSIDE the loop, which is not the case. The only code that modifies the array is code OUTISDE of the loop, which is why it's very strange that the first part of the loop in which the array is accessed doesn't crash but the second part does, even though the code in between DOESN'T change the array.

EDIT 3: Ok so a lot of the replies have been asking for the COMPLETE code. I have update the code with all the relevant REAL code.

Comment: If the second place person modifies the array then the length is no longer valid. Eg. When the player deletes the value in the array if there's a value in the index that is +1 greater than what is deleted. It will cause errors. Or it will be undefined and out of range of the new array index. As stated in the below comment the array values need to be preserved if you're relying on them in this aspect. May also need to pass additional information to dowhatever() because you need to check if value is null.

Comment: My doWhatever() function doesn't change the array at all.. the event listener for the disconnect event does.

Comment: is the disconnect function deleting or replacing a value from the array? If it's deleting then all values after thatvare shifted by one index. If there's only two players it's deleting the last index and making the access to that index out of bounds (undefined). Also the function isn't being interrupted because of the nature of async. The code is being executed on the event stack. Which is kinda like being interrupted. The big thing is change the modifications of the gamesWorld array so that second place person changes the value to falsey as opposed to being null.

Comment: Yes, the disconnect function is deleting a part of the array. But that function isn't called in the code inside the loop. The code inside the loop DOES NOT change the array.

Comment: As I said in the comment on my answer, if ANY other code is running while this function is running, then this function must be yielding control via some asynchronous operation. Javascript does NOT interrupt a running piece of code to process other events. It just doesn't do that. If you make some async call and then have a callback that is hooked up to get called when the async call is done, then the JS engine is absolutely free to service other event BEFORE that async callback gets called. You will have to show us more of your real code for us to help further beyond hypothetical guesses.

Comment: Ok I have made edits, now my question contains the real code.

Comment: What is the error message, do you have anything in the logs? It's hard to believe that socket.io does not respect the event loop. There may be something else going on here... It would be nice to reduce this to a ws or stream module code instead of a socket.io code.

Comment: The error message basically is saying that it cannot call clearGameState of undefined.. And I know that the reason it can't is because the array has been modified when the disconnect event occurs so there is no element to call clearGameState on. In the second log message in the loop where I log the gameWorld length, the log says that the length is 0 but in that same iteration the length was greater than 0 for the first log message.

Comment: Besides the one call to `setImmediate(update)` that you show, what else causes `update()` to get called?

Comment: Update is only called via setImmediate.. nothing else calls it.

Comment: Can you recap the problem?  Are you saying that sometimes when `update()` is running that something modifies the `gameWorlds` array while `update()` is running?  Is that what you're saying?  And, you think that what is modifying the array is the `disconnect` event handler?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem. The only code that changes the array is in that disconnect event handler. According to @Ravenous it's possible that my function is getting interrupted and then being resumed because of how the call stack works.. I am just interested in knowing if there's a way to stop that.

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't see how that can happen given this code.  `update()` is synchronous.  Once started, it will complete its execution before the `disconnect` event can be processed.  That's just how Javascript in node.js works.  Now, something else could be calling `update()` somewhere and that could be really confusing you.  Or something that `update()` does or calls could be modifying your array and that could be showing you the issue.  Or something could be synchronously emitting a disconnect event (shame on that code) rather than it coming from a disconnected socket.

Comment: Hmm.. I have closely examined my code already which is why I came to stack overflow. My biggest problem is the fact that my server doesn't crash when the array is accessed first but it crashes in the second access in the SAME interation. The reason I can say that is because of the log messages (the first one in the loop happens, then the disconnect one, and then finally the second log message in the loop.) In other words, the disconnect event handler ran in between the two logs in the loop. There is no other way of explaining it..

Comment: If you claim that the disconnect event handler crashes the socket.io server, because it interrupts a sync code, then please provide some evidence. e.g. a simple example app with an example client, which crashes the server. Without it we won't believe that this happens, since the nodejs event loop works completely differently. I voted on close because of this.

Comment: I did give the evidence in my question with the updated code.. that's the simplified version. The only relevant code in the client is that it's calling io.connect() to connect to the server. So it's right there..  you seem very confident in how the event loop works, yet can you provide an alternative explanation as to how a console log from ANOTHER function is inserted in between 2 console logs in the currently running function(without calling the other function ofc)? The ONLY way this could happen is if that other function is being called in the middle of the current function that's running.

Comment: Ravenous's explanation makes a lot more sense because he's suggesting that the function IS getting interrupted but just not in parallel (b/c nodejs is single threaded), which is the most reasonable suggestion. I would just like a little more information which is why I still haven't chosen an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript in node.js is single threaded.  A given thread of execution in Javascript will NOT be interrupted by a socket.io disconnect event.  That physically can't happen.  node.js is event driven.  When the disconnect event happens, an event will be put into the Javascript event queue and ONLY when your current thread of execution is done will Javascript grab the next event out of the event queue and call the callback associated with it.

You don't show enough of your real code to know for sure, but what could be happening is if you have asynchronous operations, then when you start an async operation and register a callback for its completion, then you are finishing that Javascript thread of execution and it is merely a race to see which async event happens next (the completion of this specific async operation or the disconnect event from the socket.io disconnect).  That is indeterminate and those events can happen in any order.  So, if you have async code in the code in question, then the disconnect event can get processed while that code is waiting for a completion of an async event.

---

That is the type of race conditions that you have to be aware of in node.js programming.  Anytime your logic goes asynchronous, then other things can get processed in node.js while your code is waiting for the asynchronous callback that signals the operation is complete.

What exactly to do about this depends entirely upon the exact situation and we would need to see and understand your real code (not pseudo code) to know which option to best recommend to you.  FYI, this is one of the reasons we can always help you better if you show us your real code, not just pseudo code.

Here are some of the techniques that can be used when you are operating with async operations on a shared data structure that could be changed by other async code:

1. Make a copy of the data you want to process so no other code has access to your copy so it can't be modified by any other code.  This might be making a copy of an array or it might be just using a closure to capture an index locally so the index can't be impacted by other code.
2. Use a flag to protect a data structure that is in the middle of being modified and train all other code to respect that flag.  How exactly to do this depends upon the specific data.  I have code in a Raspberry Pi node.js app that regularly saves data to disk and is subject to a race condition where other event driven code may want to update that data while I'm in the middle of using async I/O to write it to disk.  Because the data is potentially large and the memory of the system not so large, I can't make a copy of the data as suggested in the first point.  So, I used a flag to indicate that I'm in the middle of writing the data to disk and any code that wishes to modify the data while this flag is set, adds its operations to a queue rather than directly modifies the data.  Then, when I'm done writing the data to disk, the code checks the queue to see if any pending operations need to be carried out to modify the data.  And, since the data is represented by an object and all operations on the data are carried out by methods on the object, this is all made transparent to the code using the data or trying to modify the data.
3. Put the data in an actual database that has concurrency features and controls built into it so that it can make atomic changes to the data or data can be locked for brief periods of time or data can be fetched or updated in a safe way.  Databases have lots of possible strategies for dealing with this since it happens with them a lot.
4. Make all accesses to the data be asynchronous so if some other async operation is in the middle of modifying the data, then other unsafe attempts to access the data can "block" until the original operation is done.  This is one technique that databases use.  You do, of course, have to watch out for deadlocks or for error paths where the flags or locks aren't cleared.

---

Some new comments based on your posting of more code:

This code is just wrong:

```
//in the main module (the same one as the update function), the listener      
//function that's called in the disconnect event handler:
function networkEventsListener(eventType, eventObject){
   if(eventType === "disconnect"){
       for(var i = 0; i < gameWorlds.length; i++){
            if(gameWorlds[i].id === eventObject){
                gameWorlds.splice(i, 1); 
                console.log("GAME WORLD DELETED");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

When you call `.splice()` in the middle of a `for` loop on the array you are iterating, it causes you to miss an item in the array you are iterating.  I don't know if this has anything to do with your issue, but it is wrong.  One simple way to avoid this issue it to iterate the array backwards.  Then calling `.splice()` will not influence the position of any of the array elements that you have not yet iterated and you won't miss anything in the array.

Same issue in the `for` loop in your `disconnect` handler.  If you only ever expect one array element to match in your iteration, then you can `break` right after the `splice()` and this will avoid this issue and you won't have to iterate backwards.

Comment: In the first part of your response. you said that execution can't be interrupted. Please take a look at my edits because my situation strongly suggests that my function is getting interrupted.

Comment: @TheMAAAN -  You likely have some asynchronous code with callbacks inside your loop.  You will have to show that code for us to help you.   Asynchronous callbacks are executed some time into the future while the rest of your code continues uninterrupted.  So, nothing is getting interrupted.  It's just that your async callbacks are scheduled to happen in the future (that's how async works in Javascript).  You have to code a different way to use the results of those async callbacks.  So, it looks like your question is not showing the most important aspects of your code in that loop.

Comment: @ your new comments... I see your point but I could just do "i--;" in the if statement so in the next iteration the "i" variable will be indexing the next element (due to the nature of splice() in that if I delete an element the next element will be at the index of the deleted element. This will prevent the loop from skipping any elements.) Thank you for this! Although this isn't related to the issue because currently the array will only have 1 element in it (I will deal with many elements after I resolve my current issues.)

Comment: @TheMAAAN - Yes you could do that, but it's really ugly code to do that.  Moving `for` indexes around in the middle of the iteration is just asking for hard to read/understand/maintain code.  If you aren't expecting multiple matches, then just `break` out of the loop after you find a match.  Or, iterate backwards.

Comment: @TheMAAAN - And if you're going to use this type of code to remove matching items from an array in multiple places, make one utility function that does it correctly that you can just call in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I think you should change to fix the problem.

1) don't modify the length of the array when disconnect occurs but instead make a value that is falsey. A boolean or a one and zero scenario

2) add logic in the form of an if statement to check if the value is falsey for player two. That way you'll know they disconnected and don't deserve to have anything because they're lame and couldn't watch the loser screen.

That should fix the issue and you can. Decide what to do if they're to lazy to stay and watch the winning losing ceremony of your game.

var gameWorld = [ ];

`function update(){ // some code }`  is async and is pushed to the event loop.
`function disconnect(){ // some code }` is also async and gets pushed to the event loop.

Even though `update()` is running on the call stack it's waiting for the event loop and it doesn't mean that it'll complete it's execution before the next tick occurs. `gameWorld` is outside both scopes it can be modified in the middle of `update()`. So when update() tries to access the array again it's different then when it started.

disconnect() is called before update() finishes and modifies the array on the event loop nexttick() thus by the time the code for update() gets to second player bam the array is messed up.

Comment: But if the disconnect function can't fire mid execution of the loop, then even if it modifies the array it shouldn't matter because that modification will be taken into account for the next loop. My problem lies in the fact that when the array is accessed in the first part of the loop, my program doesn't crash but as soon as it reaches the second part (this is the same iteration of the loop btw) it crashes. Also, the console log message in the disconnect event handler appears before the second console log in my loop.

Comment: function update(){ // some code }  is async and is pushed to teh event loop.

then 

function disconnect is also

Comment: Yes, but how come the program doesn't crash when the array is accessed in the first place of the loop but it crashes when it's accessed in the second part of the loop in the same iteration?

Comment: @TheMAAAN it's crashing the second time because the array length is undefined thus causing an error in the program. The first time around the array has an index of 0 and 1 (assuming two player) and a gameWorld.length of 2 but because disconnect modified the array before second player part is occurring the array is now only holding an index of 0 and a gameWorld.length of 1 so when i = 1 there is no index at position 1 becuase it's undefined in the array. Causing an error and an exception and crashing.

Comment: No I understand that, which is exactly the problem! But that means that the disconnect event handler is called mid execution because if it's not then the program should ALWAYS crash in the first access of the array..

Comment: @TheMAAAN that's because update() is not on the main thread it's on the call stack. Being processed by the event loop. Thus leaving the main stack to call disconnect() but then when update() gets around to accessing its messed up. So yes it is executing during the for loop.

Comment: I thought node had no concurrency... everything was async. So how would I make everything in one thread then?

Comment: It's because you have another async function occurring in your for loop. which is going over the network. which according to the event loop frees up the next.tick() to handle what's next in the call stack, which in this case is your disconnect() function. It is in one thread it just because a network call is async it's thrown on a separate stack to be processed by the browser (the browsers stack.) you'd have to take out the async function from your for loop. you've basically have a nodeJS no no in your logic.

Additionally i've told you how to fix your issue with my suggested changes

Comment: Are you saying socket.emit is an async call?

Comment: I could use the strategy of having falsey values.. but I am just wondering if there is a way in which I could prevent anything from getting interrupted even if it runs over the time of the next tick.

Comment: You are using  a library with a main focus of constructing event listeners. you could make a listener in the disconnect function check if the stack is free, I mean really it's endless its bout how you decide to program.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have an event listener, execution should not just stop mid function. When the event occurs, node will push the event callback on to the stack. Then when node finishes executing the current function it will start processing the other requests on the stack. You can't be sure of the order things will execute, but you can be sure that things will not get interrupted mid execution.

If your doWhatever function is async then the problem may be occurring because when node finally gets around to servicing the requests on the stack the loop has already finished, therefore everytime doWhatever is called it is being called with the same index (whatever its last value was.)

If you want to call async functions from a loop then you should wrap them in a function to preserve the arguments.

e.g.

```
function doWhateverWrapper(index){
    theArray[index].doWhatever();
}

function update(){
   for(var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++){
      //first place the array is accessed
      doWhateverWrapper(i);

      ....more code.....

      //second place the array is accessed
      doWhateverWrapper(i);
   }
}
setImmediate(update);
```

Comment: You said execution should not just stop mid-function. In my real code, I have two console logs in the loop(one right before the first place and one right before the second place, Look at my edit.). I also have a console log in the disconnect event listener. How come when my server crashes the console log in the disconnect event listener fires after the first console log message in the loop but BEFORE the second console log message? My loop is being interupted it's the only explanation..

Comment: @TheMAAAN Can you post all the code that goes in the loop, there must be something in there that is relevant to the results you are seeing.

Comment: Ok I have posted all the real relevant code to my situation (i.e. the disconnect event handler, the code inside the loop, etc.)